Ubuntu пропадает значок wifi
При попытке подключения к вайфаю пропадает на пару секунд значок вайфая (если открыть настройки, то при попытке подключения и в настройках пункт пропадает), не работают никакие режимы модема на телефоне, ни USB ни Bluetooth, самое главное - при загрузке с флешки все работало. Последнее, что я делал на компе это пытался поднять среду разработки по работе, пытался ставить то ли pyenv то ли pipenv, не помню что последнее. Потом врубил спящий режим и в электричке уже нихрена не работало. Когда загрузился с флешки первый раз была та же проблема. Загрузился с флешки через день с отключением загрузки с диска и все заработало. Настройки fast boot в uefi не вижу. Сносить Ubuntu не хотелось бы, долго и неприятно, есть варик переустановить уже лежащие на ноуте драйвера, интернет просто никак не подрубить, нет разъёма патчкорда.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
